# How to push an array into an Object which is inside of another array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, chart.js

Inside a for loop, am trying to push variable array inside an object which in turn is inside an array.
I am trying to push the data here:
[image]

Expanded view:
[image]

Data final location:
[image]

This is my code:

```
let that.dynamicDataCollection3 = [];
let allDeptNames=["Dept 1","Dept 2","Dept 3","Dept 4","Dept 17"];
let insPerDay = [[["1538474655452","1538474655636","1538474655834","1538474656089","1538474751210","1538474751377","1538474751543","1538474751694","1538474755196","1538474755348","1538485850074","1538485850431","1538485850790","1538485851228"],["1538523551485","1538523551643","1538523551803","1538523552041","1538523552369","1538523553456","1538523553607","1538523553805","1538523554800","1538523554954","1538523555094","1538523555245","1538523555396","1538523555555","1538523557272","1538523557432","1538523557590","1538523557742","1538523557893","1538523558039","1538523558195","1538523559984","1538523564305","1538523564586","1538523564656","1538523568428","1538523568618","1538523569008","1538523569161","1538523571608","1538523572092","1538523572236","1538523572380","1538523572547","1538523572720","1538523572888"],["1538662645663","1538662645815","1538662645982","1538662646160","1538662646332","1538662646531","1538662650368","1538662650528","1538662650703","1538662652400","1538662714705","1538662714888","1538662715071","1538662715264","1538662715468","1538662715675"],["1538730663891","1538730664336"],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],["1538523631290","1538523631442","1538523631602","1538523631770","1538523634732","1538523634876","1538523635043","1538523635197","1538523635370","1538523635560","1538523635727","1538523635894","1538523636061","1538523636227","1538523636403","1538523636578","1538523636752","1538523636927","1538523637103","1538523637285","1538523637460","1538523637667","1538523637874","1538523638073","1538523638250","1538523638430","1538523638637","1538523638827","1538523639105","1538523639268","1538523639480","1538523639678","1538523639948","1538523640075","1538523640522","1538523640772","1538523640936","1538523641126","1538523641325","1538523641502","1538523641674","1538523641857","1538523642039","1538523642262","1538523642453","1538523642621","1538523643009","1538523643220","1538523643431","1538523643854","1538523644138","1538523648438","1538523648606","1538523648778","1538523728062","1538523728332","1538523728516","1538523728694","1538523728881","1538523729376","1538523734863","1538523735038","1538523735204","1538523735371","1538523735531","1538550110609"],["1538662662501","1538662662667","1538662662819","1538662662970","1538662663138","1538662663288","1538662726568","1538662726735","1538662726902","1538662727068","1538662727247","1538662727426","1538662727704"],["1538730451253","1538730451387","1538730451522","1538730451664","1538730451812","1538730451979","1538730500737","1538736000601","1538736000774","1538736000934","1538736001085","1538736001238"],[],[],[],[],[]],[[],["1538523539833","1538523539993","1538523540198","1538523541522","1538523541681","1538523541841","1538523543200","1538523543382","1538523543542","1538523598082","1538523598258","1538523598416","1538523598566","1538523598718","1538523598878","1538523657714","1538523657945","1538523658485","1538523658711","1538552669959","1538552671158","1538552689892"],["1538662672939","1538662673094","1538662673256","1538662673414","1538662673573","1538662673739","1538662673898","1538662674049","1538662674201","1538662674359","1538662674523","1538662706978"],["1538730485439","1538730485580","1538730485743","1538730485874","1538730486049","1538730486200","1538730486358","1538730486510"],[],[],[],[],[]],[["1538474676007","1538474676181","1538474676357","1538474676691","1538474676865","1538474677032","1538474677199","1538474681585","1538474681734","1538474681895","1538474682061","1538474682412","1538474682578","1538474685580","1538474685742","1538474685914","1538474688908","1538474689074","1538474689266","1538474887658","1538474887847","1538474888022","1538474888181","1538474888364"],["1538523513934","1538523514093","1538523514251","1538523514402","1538523514562","1538523514714","1538523516390","1538523516542","1538523516693","1538523520990","1538523521148","1538523521329","1538523521467","1538523521626","1538523521804","1538523521970","1538523523968","1538523528670","1538523529537","1538523529721","1538523529871","1538523530014","1538523530364","1538523530515"],[],["1538730493512","1538730493653","1538730493789","1538730493933","1538730494067","1538730494210","1538730494352"],[],[],[],[],[]],[["1538497087788"],["1538523492819","1538523493057","1538523493307","1538523493708","1538523493884","1538523494098","1538523495942","1538523496133","1538523826322","1538523826488","1538523826680","1538523826847","1538523827176","1538577571657","1538577572300","1538577572817","1538577573806","1538577574157","1538577663486"],["1538609439534","1538609439717","1538609439843","1538609440009","1538609440177","1538609440336","1538609440510","1538609440670","1538609440828","1538609440995","1538609441171","1538609441328","1538609441495","1538609441671","1538609442078","1538609442287","1538609442468","1538662608664","1538662608864","1538662609007","1538662609151","1538662609302","1538662609444","1538662609590","1538662612208","1538662612359","1538662612487","1538662612630","1538662614708","1538662614872","1538662615057","1538662615476","1538662615848","1538662616023","1538662616284","1538662616451","1538662616595","1538662622515","1538662622520","1538662624213","1538662624381","1538662624548","1538662624732","1538662627936","1538662628119","1538662631634","1538662631639","1538662632602","1538662632840","1538662635778","1538663768834","1538663768995","1538663769147","1538663769284","1538663769424","1538663769559","1538663769694","1538663769837","1538663769984","1538663770118","1538663770268","1538663770434","1538663770568"],["1538730505799","1538730505940","1538730506083","1538730506225","1538730506360","1538730506496","1538730506649"],[],[],[],[],[]]]
let that = this; 
let lineColours = ['rgba(248,121,121, 0.9)', 'rgba(255, 80, 248, 0.9)', 'rgba(159, 255, 252, 0.9)', 'rgba(191, 164, 199, 0.9)',  'rgba(206, 255, 225, 0.9)', 'rgba(253, 233, 255, 0.9)']
        let lineBackColours = ['rgba(248,121,121, 0.06)', 'rgba(255, 80, 248, 0.06)', 'rgba(159, 255, 252, 0.06)', 'rgba(191, 164, 199, 0.06)',  'rgba(206, 255, 225, 0.06)', 'rgba(253, 233, 255, 0.06)']
        let datasets = [];
        let datasets_temp = [];
        let data = [];
        for (i =0; i < allDeptNames.length; i++) {

            let datasets = [
                {
                label: allDeptNames[i],
                backgroundColor: lineColours[i],
                backgroundColor: lineBackColours[i],
                borderColor: lineColours[i],
                borderWidth: 2,
                }
            ]
            for (let ipd=0; ipd<insPerDay[i].length; ipd++){
                    let datasets_temp= [insPerDay[i][ipd].length];
                    data.push(datasets_temp)
            }
            datasets.push(data );
            data = [];
            that.dynamicDataCollection3.push(datasets);
        }
```

Which is logging this (pushing the data outside the object):

[image]

The intended Output of **that.dynamicDataCollection** object/array should be something like this:

```
[
   [{"label":"Dept 1","backgroundColor":"rgba(248,121,121, 0.06)","data":[0,9,31,14,36,16,2, 0,0,0],"borderColor":"rgba(248,121,121, 0.9)","borderWidth":2}],
   [{"label":"Dept 2","backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 80, 248, 0.06)","data":[0,0,43,0,66,13,12, 0,0,0],"borderColor":"rgba(255, 80, 248, 0.9)","borderWidth":2}],
   [{"label":"Dept 3","backgroundColor":"rgba(159, 255, 252, 0.06)","data":[0,0,49,0,22,12,8, 0,0,0],"borderColor":"rgba(159, 255, 252, 0.9)","borderWidth":2}],
   [{"label":"Dept 4","backgroundColor":"rgba(191, 164, 199, 0.06)","data":[0,0,25,24,24,0,7, 0,0,0],"borderColor":"rgba(191, 164, 199,0.9)","borderWidth":2}],
   [{"label":"Dept17","backgroundColor":"rgba(206,255, 225, 0.06)","data"[0,0,0,1,19,63,7, 0,0,0],"borderColor":"rgba(206, 255, 225, 0.9)","borderWidth":2}]
]
```

The intended result as an image:
[image]

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Where's `allDeptNames`? It can't be declared within a loop that it is being compared to.

Comment: Please show us a small sample of actual JSON input and expected output, that will help.

Comment: To let your question more clear, i suggest to [edit] it to show these informations:
Your issue and objective, an example of actual object result (as code/log, not image) and an example of the desired result (as code/log, not image). That would help a lot

Comment: _that_ does not seem to be defined anywhere, you're not adding a _data_ property.

Comment: I have added some of the missing variables: "allDeptNames", "insPerDay", "that". Sorry about that...

Comment: _How to push an array into an Object which is inside of another array?_ `[].push({ array: [1,2,3] })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

- I added an empty array `data` to your `datasets` template

  ```
      let datasets = [
          {
            label: allDeptNames[i],
            backgroundColor: lineColours[i],
            backgroundColor: lineBackColours[i],
            borderColor: lineColours[i],
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: [] // <- Add this
          }
        ]
  ```
- An change `datasets.push(data );` into `datasets[0].data = data.map(i => i[0]);`

```js
let allDeptNames = ["Dept 1", "Dept 2", "Dept 3", "Dept 4", "Dept 17"];
let insPerDay = [
  [
    ["1538474655452", "1538474655636", "1538474655834", "1538474656089", "1538474751210", "1538474751377", "1538474751543", "1538474751694", "1538474755196", "1538474755348", "1538485850074", "1538485850431", "1538485850790", "1538485851228"],
    ["1538523551485", "1538523551643", "1538523551803", "1538523552041", "1538523552369", "1538523553456", "1538523553607", "1538523553805", "1538523554800", "1538523554954", "1538523555094", "1538523555245", "1538523555396", "1538523555555", "1538523557272", "1538523557432", "1538523557590", "1538523557742", "1538523557893", "1538523558039", "1538523558195", "1538523559984", "1538523564305", "1538523564586", "1538523564656", "1538523568428", "1538523568618", "1538523569008", "1538523569161", "1538523571608", "1538523572092", "1538523572236", "1538523572380", "1538523572547", "1538523572720", "1538523572888"],
    ["1538662645663", "1538662645815", "1538662645982", "1538662646160", "1538662646332", "1538662646531", "1538662650368", "1538662650528", "1538662650703", "1538662652400", "1538662714705", "1538662714888", "1538662715071", "1538662715264", "1538662715468", "1538662715675"],
    ["1538730663891", "1538730664336"],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ],
  [
    [],
    ["1538523631290", "1538523631442", "1538523631602", "1538523631770", "1538523634732", "1538523634876", "1538523635043", "1538523635197", "1538523635370", "1538523635560", "1538523635727", "1538523635894", "1538523636061", "1538523636227", "1538523636403", "1538523636578", "1538523636752", "1538523636927", "1538523637103", "1538523637285", "1538523637460", "1538523637667", "1538523637874", "1538523638073", "1538523638250", "1538523638430", "1538523638637", "1538523638827", "1538523639105", "1538523639268", "1538523639480", "1538523639678", "1538523639948", "1538523640075", "1538523640522", "1538523640772", "1538523640936", "1538523641126", "1538523641325", "1538523641502", "1538523641674", "1538523641857", "1538523642039", "1538523642262", "1538523642453", "1538523642621", "1538523643009", "1538523643220", "1538523643431", "1538523643854", "1538523644138", "1538523648438", "1538523648606", "1538523648778", "1538523728062", "1538523728332", "1538523728516", "1538523728694", "1538523728881", "1538523729376", "1538523734863", "1538523735038", "1538523735204", "1538523735371", "1538523735531", "1538550110609"],
    ["1538662662501", "1538662662667", "1538662662819", "1538662662970", "1538662663138", "1538662663288", "1538662726568", "1538662726735", "1538662726902", "1538662727068", "1538662727247", "1538662727426", "1538662727704"],
    ["1538730451253", "1538730451387", "1538730451522", "1538730451664", "1538730451812", "1538730451979", "1538730500737", "1538736000601", "1538736000774", "1538736000934", "1538736001085", "1538736001238"],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ],
  [
    [],
    ["1538523539833", "1538523539993", "1538523540198", "1538523541522", "1538523541681", "1538523541841", "1538523543200", "1538523543382", "1538523543542", "1538523598082", "1538523598258", "1538523598416", "1538523598566", "1538523598718", "1538523598878", "1538523657714", "1538523657945", "1538523658485", "1538523658711", "1538552669959", "1538552671158", "1538552689892"],
    ["1538662672939", "1538662673094", "1538662673256", "1538662673414", "1538662673573", "1538662673739", "1538662673898", "1538662674049", "1538662674201", "1538662674359", "1538662674523", "1538662706978"],
    ["1538730485439", "1538730485580", "1538730485743", "1538730485874", "1538730486049", "1538730486200", "1538730486358", "1538730486510"],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ],
  [
    ["1538474676007", "1538474676181", "1538474676357", "1538474676691", "1538474676865", "1538474677032", "1538474677199", "1538474681585", "1538474681734", "1538474681895", "1538474682061", "1538474682412", "1538474682578", "1538474685580", "1538474685742", "1538474685914", "1538474688908", "1538474689074", "1538474689266", "1538474887658", "1538474887847", "1538474888022", "1538474888181", "1538474888364"],
    ["1538523513934", "1538523514093", "1538523514251", "1538523514402", "1538523514562", "1538523514714", "1538523516390", "1538523516542", "1538523516693", "1538523520990", "1538523521148", "1538523521329", "1538523521467", "1538523521626", "1538523521804", "1538523521970", "1538523523968", "1538523528670", "1538523529537", "1538523529721", "1538523529871", "1538523530014", "1538523530364", "1538523530515"],
    [],
    ["1538730493512", "1538730493653", "1538730493789", "1538730493933", "1538730494067", "1538730494210", "1538730494352"],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ],
  [
    ["1538497087788"],
    ["1538523492819", "1538523493057", "1538523493307", "1538523493708", "1538523493884", "1538523494098", "1538523495942", "1538523496133", "1538523826322", "1538523826488", "1538523826680", "1538523826847", "1538523827176", "1538577571657", "1538577572300", "1538577572817", "1538577573806", "1538577574157", "1538577663486"],
    ["1538609439534", "1538609439717", "1538609439843", "1538609440009", "1538609440177", "1538609440336", "1538609440510", "1538609440670", "1538609440828", "1538609440995", "1538609441171", "1538609441328", "1538609441495", "1538609441671", "1538609442078", "1538609442287", "1538609442468", "1538662608664", "1538662608864", "1538662609007", "1538662609151", "1538662609302", "1538662609444", "1538662609590", "1538662612208", "1538662612359", "1538662612487", "1538662612630", "1538662614708", "1538662614872", "1538662615057", "1538662615476", "1538662615848", "1538662616023", "1538662616284", "1538662616451", "1538662616595", "1538662622515", "1538662622520", "1538662624213", "1538662624381", "1538662624548", "1538662624732", "1538662627936", "1538662628119", "1538662631634", "1538662631639", "1538662632602", "1538662632840", "1538662635778", "1538663768834", "1538663768995", "1538663769147", "1538663769284", "1538663769424", "1538663769559", "1538663769694", "1538663769837", "1538663769984", "1538663770118", "1538663770268", "1538663770434", "1538663770568"],
    ["1538730505799", "1538730505940", "1538730506083", "1538730506225", "1538730506360", "1538730506496", "1538730506649"],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
  ]
]
let that = this;
let lineColours = ['rgba(248,121,121, 0.9)', 'rgba(255, 80, 248, 0.9)', 'rgba(159, 255, 252, 0.9)', 'rgba(191, 164, 199, 0.9)', 'rgba(206, 255, 225, 0.9)', 'rgba(253, 233, 255, 0.9)']
let lineBackColours = ['rgba(248,121,121, 0.06)', 'rgba(255, 80, 248, 0.06)', 'rgba(159, 255, 252, 0.06)', 'rgba(191, 164, 199, 0.06)', 'rgba(206, 255, 225, 0.06)', 'rgba(253, 233, 255, 0.06)']
let datasets = [];
let datasets_temp = [];
let data = [];
let dynamicDataCollection3 = [];
for (i = 0; i < allDeptNames.length; i++) {

  let datasets = [{
    label: allDeptNames[i],
    backgroundColor: lineColours[i],
    backgroundColor: lineBackColours[i],
    borderColor: lineColours[i],
    borderWidth: 2,
    data: []
  }]
  for (let ipd = 0; ipd < insPerDay[i].length; ipd++) {
    let datasets_temp = [insPerDay[i][ipd].length];
    data.push(datasets_temp)
  }
  datasets[0].data = data.map(i => i[0]);
  data = [];
  dynamicDataCollection3.push(datasets);
}


console.log(dynamicDataCollection3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
that.dynamicDataCollection3[i].push({data: datasets});
```